# Tikz: How to display properly some linked nodes?

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, nodes

I have created the following diagram using Tikz, is there anyway to show it properly? (As it is, it is shown with all the nodes below the last one, so it is a mess)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[spanish]{babel}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows}

\tikzstyle{io} = [ellipse, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black, fill=blue!30]
\tikzstyle{arrow} = [thick,->,>=stealth]

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2cm]
\node (1) [io] {1 1 1 1};
\node (2) [io, below of=1] {2 1 0 1};
\node (3) [io, below of=2] {1 0 1 2};
\node (4) [io, below of=3] {2 0 0 2};
\node (5) [io, below of=4] {0 0 2 2};
\node (6) [io, below of=5] {0 1 2 1};
\node (7) [io, below of=6] {0 2 2 0};
\node (8) [io, below of=7] {1 2 1 0};
\node (9) [io, below of=8] {2 2 0 0};

\draw [arrow] (1) -- node {t1} (2);
\draw [arrow] (2) -- node {t2} (3);
\draw [arrow] (3) -- node {t1} (4);
\draw [arrow] (4) -- node {t3} (2);
\draw [arrow] (3) -- node {t3} (1);
\draw [arrow] (2) -- node {t3} (9);
\draw [arrow] (9) -- node {t2} (1);
\draw [arrow] (1) -- node {t3} (8);
\draw [arrow] (1) -- node {t2} (5);
\draw [arrow] (5) -- node {t1} (3);
\draw [arrow] (5) -- node {t3} (6);
\draw [arrow] (6) -- node {t1} (1);
\draw [arrow] (6) -- node {t3} (7);
\draw [arrow] (7) -- node {t1} (8);
\draw [arrow] (8) -- node {t2} (6);
\draw [arrow] (8) -- node {t1} (9);

\end{tikzpicture}    
\end{document}
```

For example, how could i show the nodes in a circle layout?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You said "in a circle layout". Here is an example. You can place the nodes around node (1) using `at (<angle:distance>)` macro.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[spanish]{babel}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows}

\tikzstyle{io} = [ellipse, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black, fill=blue!30]
\tikzstyle{arrow} = [thick,->,>=stealth]

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}%[node distance=2cm]
\node (1) [io] {1 1 1 1};
\node (2) [io] at (45:2in) {2 1 0 1};
\node (4) [io] at (90:2in) {2 0 0 2};
\node (3) [io] at (135:2in) {1 0 1 2};
\node (5) [io] at (180:2in) {0 0 2 2};
\node (6) [io] at (225:2in) {0 1 2 1};
\node (7) [io] at (270:2in) {0 2 2 0};
\node (8) [io] at (315:2in) {1 2 1 0};
\node (9) [io] at (360:2in) {2 2 0 0};

\draw [arrow] (1) -- node[auto] {t1} (2);    %% note auto option here onwards
                                             %%        for proper placement.
\draw [arrow] (2) -- node[auto] {t2} (3);
\draw [arrow] (3) -- node[auto] {t1} (4);
\draw [arrow] (4) -- node[auto,xshift=1cm] {t3} (2);
\draw [arrow] (3) -- node[auto] {t3} (1);
\draw [arrow] (2) -- node[auto] {t3} (9);
\draw [arrow] (9) -- node[auto] {t2} (1);
\draw [arrow] (1) -- node[auto] {t3} (8);
\draw [arrow] (1) -- node[auto] {t2} (5);
\draw [arrow] (5) -- node[auto] {t1} (3);
\draw [arrow] (5) -- node[auto] {t3} (6);
\draw [arrow] (6) -- node[auto] {t1} (1);
\draw [arrow] (6) -- node[auto] {t3} (7);
\draw [arrow] (7) -- node[auto] {t1} (8);
\draw [arrow] (8) -- node[auto] {t2} (6);
\draw [arrow] (8) -- node[auto] {t1} (9);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You may adjust the topology by yourself to suit your needs.

Comment: @Trollkemada You are welcome. Glad it helped. :)

Comment: @HarishKumar if you swapped `1012` and `2002`, it would have more symmetry.

Comment: @Thruston Great suggestion. Thanks. Edited. I am quiet bad in topology. :)

Answer (score 4):

Here is something that should get you started using the `to` syntax and specify the anchors and teh `in=`, `out=` angles for the arrows.

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[spanish]{babel}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows}

\tikzstyle{io} = [ellipse, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black, fill=blue!30]
\tikzstyle{arrow} = [thick,->,>=stealth]

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2cm]
\node (1) [io] {1 1 1 1};
\node (2) [io, below of=1] {2 1 0 1};
\node (3) [io, below of=2] {1 0 1 2};
\node (4) [io, below of=3] {2 0 0 2};
%\node (5) [io, below of=4] {0 0 2 2};
%\node (6) [io, below of=5] {0 1 2 1};
%\node (7) [io, below of=6] {0 2 2 0};
%\node (8) [io, below of=7] {1 2 1 0};
%\node (9) [io, below of=8] {2 2 0 0};

\draw [arrow] (1.south) -- node[right] {t1} (2.north);
\draw [arrow] (2.south) -- node[right] {t2} (3.north);
\draw [arrow] (3.south) -- node[right] {t1} (4.north);
\draw [arrow,out=70,in=-70] (4.east) to node[right] {t3} (2.east);
\draw [arrow,out=170,in=-170] (3.west) to node[left] {t3} (1.west);
%\draw [arrow] (2.south) -- node[right] {t3} (9.north);
%\draw [arrow] (9.south) -- node[right] {t2} (1.north);
%\draw [arrow] (1.south) -- node[right] {t3} (8.north);
%\draw [arrow] (1.south) -- node[right] {t2} (5.north);
%\draw [arrow] (5.south) -- node[right] {t1} (3.north);
%\draw [arrow] (5.south) -- node[right] {t3} (6.north);
%\draw [arrow] (6.south) -- node[right] {t1} (1.north);
%\draw [arrow] (6.south) -- node[right] {t3} (7.north);
%\draw [arrow] (7.south) -- node[right] {t1} (8.north);
%\draw [arrow] (8.south) -- node[right] {t2} (6.north);
%\draw [arrow] (8.south) -- node[right] {t1} (9.north);

\end{tikzpicture}    
\end{document}
```